# Check whether method named in a string is defined before calling it with send

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def say_hi
    puts 'hi'
end

greeting = 'say_hi'
send greeting # works

greeting = 'say_hix'
send greeting # undefined method `say_hix' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Thus in case of a typo I want to first check if the method exists; something like:

```
send greeting if greeting.is_a_method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**respond_to?**](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/respond_to%3F)

> Returns true if obj responds to the given method. Private and protected methods are included in the search only if the optional second parameter evaluates to true.

```
respond_to?(greeting)
```

> respond_to? does not work.

I've tried the following with IRB, and it works fine:

```
2.6.3 :001 > def say_hi
2.6.3 :002?>       puts 'hi'
2.6.3 :003?>   end
 => :say_hi 
2.6.3 :004 > greeting = 'say_hi'
 => "say_hi" 
2.6.3 :005 > send greeting if respond_to?(greeting) 
hi
 => nil 
2.6.3 :006 > greeting = 'say_hix'
 => "say_hix" 
2.6.3 :007 > send greeting if respond_to?(greeting)
 => nil
```

> Could you please try it in a file?

As the documentation says, `respond_to?` *includes private and protected methods only if you pass a second optional parameter and it evaluates to `true`*. Since `say_hi` is a private method, you need to pass in the second optional parameter:

```
def say_hi
    puts 'hi'
end

greeting = 'say_hi'
send(greeting) if respond_to?(greeting, true) 

greeting = 'say_hix'
send(greeting) if respond_to?(greeting, true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unless I am mistaken, `respond_to?` does not work. I tried both: `greeting = 'say_hi'; send greeting if respond_to?(greeting)` and `greeting = 'say_hix'; send greeting if respond_to?(greeting)`.

Comment: My code is just a basic script; `say_hi` is not defined in a class.

Comment: @user664833 I have updated the answer with one I tired

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the trouble. I concur that it works at the console. Could you please try it in a file? I made it executable with `chmod 700 /tmp/x.rb` and then simply ran `/tmp/x.rb`. I am using Ruby 2.6.6.

Comment: @user664833 Updated the answer, Please have a look at it